# How can I get the value of a variable from a class?

Tags: java

So I'm new to java and decided to mess around a little, I wrote a class that converts a string to an array made out of the ascii values of the characters in the string, but I don't know how to get the value of the variable i. I know it's easier to use a list but I'm really curious how to make this work. This is the code:

```
public class ToAscii {
    static int[] toAscii(String txt){
        int[] array = new int[1000];
        int i = 0;

        char[] ascii1 = txt.toCharArray();

        for(char ch:ascii1){
            array[i] = ch -1;
            i++;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "get the variable i" mean?

Comment: get it's value sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: I recommend reading tutorial on methods and return types, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Comment: If I understand what you are asking correctly, you would like to inspect the value of the variable `array`. I suggest you should use debugging. Any modern IDE supports debugging with stepping through the code line by line, and you can inspect the state of each variabele at any point. If you google for the name of you IDE and the word debugging, you will find plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is `ch -1` which should be just `ch`.

You should do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ToAscii {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toAscii("aBc")));
    }
    static int[] toAscii(String txt){
        int[] array = new int[txt.length()];
        int i = 0;

        char[] ascii1 = txt.toCharArray();

        for(char ch:ascii1){
            array[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[97, 66, 99]
```

**Alternatively**, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ToAscii {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toAscii("aBc")));
    }

    static int[] toAscii(String txt) {
        int[] array = new int[txt.length()];
        char[] ascii1 = txt.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = ascii1[i];
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[97, 66, 99]
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, but I need the value of I to itterate through the array in my main method, if I use array.length it will just output 0 for the indexes that aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

`txt.codePoints().toArray()` will convert the `String` to codepoints (ie numbers of the characters).

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("abc".codePoints().toArray()));
    }
}
```

will print:

```
[97, 98, 99]
```

where 97 corresponds to 'a', 98 to 'b' and 99 to 'c'.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think it is then how to get the i'th int from the array produced by codePoints().toArray()?

Comment: @Alex glad it helped. You can also use [charAt(i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt-int-) to get the character at position 'i' and then cast it to an int. But this approach (with charAt) will not work on all unicode characters.